Transfer Learning using Keras for Image Classification
I am trying to use an already trained model to transfer the learning to a model I will create and  modifying only the last few layers. The goal of this is to used the already trained model (trained on millions of images already) to help my model classify food item recognition. I am pretty new to Keras and I am facing an issue that I am now starting understand to  but don't know how to resolve
# Load the model from TensorFlow Hub
model_url = "https://www.kaggle.com/models/tensorflow/resnet-50/TensorFlow2/classification/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

# Create a Sequential model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

# Add the TensorFlow Hub layer to the Sequential model
model.add(hub_layer)

# Build the Sequential model
model.build((None, 224, 224, 3))

# Summary of the model
model.summary()

ERROR:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[56], line 9
      6 model = tf.keras.Sequential()
      8 # Add the TensorFlow Hub layer to the Sequential model
----> 9 model.add(hub_layer)
     11 # Build the Sequential model
     12 model.build((None, 224, 224, 3))

File c:\Users\Karim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py:95, in Sequential.add(self, layer, rebuild)
     93         layer = origin_layer
     94 if not isinstance(layer, Layer):
---> 95     raise ValueError(
     96         "Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be "
     97         f"added to a Sequential model. Received: {layer} "
     98         f"(of type {type(layer)})"
     99     )
    100 if not self._is_layer_name_unique(layer):
    101     raise ValueError(
    102         "All layers added to a Sequential model "
    103         f"should have unique names. Name '{layer.name}' is already "
    104         "the name of a layer in this model. Update the `name` argument "
    105         "to pass a unique name."
    106     )

ValueError: Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x00000190C6B8AD20> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)


The error message you're seeing is because the KerasLayer object from TensorFlow Hub is not an instance of keras.Layer, and therefore cannot be added directly to a Keras Sequential model.
To work around this you need to convert the TensorFlow Hub layer into Keras layer by using tf.keras.layers.Lambda after creating the sequential model.

You can use this right after declaring the hub_layer:
hub_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(hub_layer)

So in this particular case you're left with:
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model_url, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
hub_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(hub_layer)

